# Regex to replace file extension

Tags: php, regex

I would like a regex to replace the .html file extension with a / so www.example.com/page.html becomes www.example.com/page/. I want to also exclude a folder from this rule so anything within www.example.com/specialdir/ should be excluded.

EDIT: This will be used in php

Comment: What flavour of regex? In what language or editor?

Comment: this will be used in php

Comment: In what context does the URL appear? Is it by itself or is it just one part of a longer string? Is there more than one in a longer string? Will the URL ever have query or fragments? Its always helpful to provide some desired before and after representative examples.

Answer (score 3):

Better to use htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Source: [Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=4562)

So it will change all http://somesite/someurl to http://somesite/someurl.html in server side.

Comment: I want it the other way round....remove .html and not add. Also I want to add an exception where the rule does not apply to a certain folder

Comment: @thearchitect, do some research on htaccess and mod_rewrite.  This is probably the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @thearchitect my code does not redirect user to .html page. It does the change in server side and user sees in taskbar: http://somesite.com/somepage instead of http://somesite.com/somepage.html

Answer (score 1):

Search for

```
(www\.example\.com/(?!specialdir/).*)\.html$
```

and replace all with `\1` or `$1`, depending on your regex implementation.

EDIT: In PHP:

```
$result = preg_replace('%(www\.example\.com/(?!specialdir/).*)\.html$%', '\1', $subject);
```